# How to search for a word in column header that fully matches the word not partially?

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

I have a multicolumn text file with header in the first row like this

```
Name  xy_fill zxy_fill tz_fill 
Fox    0      5        55
Snake  1      6        14
wolf   8      1        2
```

The headers are stored in an array called `hdr`. which contains `xy_fill  tz_fill` 
I want to search for each elements of this `hdr` array from that multicolumn text file. And I am using this `awk` approach

```
for ii in ${hdr[@]}
do

  gawk -vcol="$ii" -F  $'\t' '                                 
    $0 ~ col{
   for(s=1;s<=NF;s++){                        
          heading=$s                                  
         colhdr[s]=heading
         if(index(heading, col))wanted[s]=1
       }
    }
   '

done
```

But this gives me both `xy_fill` and `zxy_fill` columns while searching for `xy_fill`. How can I only read `xy_fill` column?
For example if I search `xy_fill` it should return column number 1 but my script is returning 1 and 2, which is wrong.

Comment: Please add what how your output should look like.

Comment: Actually I want to search "xy_fill" along with a space in the front so that I can avoid confusion of scanning both "xy_fill" and "zxy_fill" while searching for "xy_fill".

Comment: In that Question, Someone asked to print columns by header name but in my case the problem is my script is getting confused with header name `xy_fill` and `zxy_fill`

Comment: **your** version gets confused, but the answers in the duplicate question won't. Did you try them? (or my `csvcut` answer below?)

Comment: Most search (regexp) machines allow to specify word boundaries, e.g. `\<fill` matches only if the word starts `fill`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -v tgt='xy_fill' 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i} {print $(f[tgt])}' file
xy_fill
0
1
8
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `csvcut` from [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```bsh
# if file is tab-delimited:
csvcut -t -c xy_fill,tz_fill file

# if file is space-delimited
csvcut -d' ' -S -c xy_fill,tz_fill file
```

For using an array as input you need to [convert it to comma-separated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9429887/7365127) values:

```
hdr=(xy_fill tz_fill)
hdr_csv=$(IFS=,;echo "${hdr[*]}")
csvcut -t -c "$hdr_csv" file # tab-delimited
# or
csvcut -d' ' -S -c "$hdr_csv" file # space-delimited
```

---

Add `| csvformat -T` at the end if you want the output to be tab-delimited again.

**Output:**

```
xy_fill tz_fill
0   55
1   14
8   2
```

Answer (score -1):

If you only want `xy_fill` why not simply `awk '{print $2}' testfile`?

Comment: Because, I don't know in which column "xy_fill" will be situated.